# is it possible in php to save changes made on web page without sending into database

Tags: php, html

I have done some research on this topic but couldn't come up with a solution.

Is it possible in php to save changes made on web page without sending the infos into database??I'm giving each user the ability to make some changes on their pages and after changes made,every visitor of that page would be able to see the new edited text.

How can I do that?

Here is the sample php code

```
<?php

  if(isset($_POST['x']) && isset($_POST['hi'])){
   $hel=$_POST['hi'];
  }
 else{
   $hel="Hello There";
  }

?>
```

HTML Part

```
<form id='sub' name='sub' method='post' action='edit.php' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
 <input type='text' id='hi' name='hi'>
 <input type='submit' id='x' name='x' value='publish'>
</form>
<?php echo $hel;?>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can edit\write files with php, if that's what you are asking

Comment: "every visitor of that page would be able to see the new edited text" You can write to the page file with the new data (usually not a good idea, read EXTENSIVELY about user input and file security etc) or update a database (you don't want, but the better solution in reality)

Comment: @James I need other users to see the changes.Like template based site.logged in user change something and other users can see when visit that page.My plan is without putting that on database,if possible

Comment: As I said "You can write to the page file with the new data". So learn about PHP file open, read, and write access functions. Open whatever.php, write to it whatever users enters in form, then save, then anyone opening that file (URL) in their browser will see the changes to the file (or be hacked, or get a virus) Letting users write to files which are served by your web server is really bad unless you're clued up on security.

Comment: very common for pages to be built from db on every load, explaining why you want a no DB approach would help. every CMS does it, perhaps you just want to install one of them

Comment: @james thanks for your suggestion,but I already know about that stuffs.I know how to put content and get content from file and this kind of stuff.Taking all the comments and answers into consideration,I think using DB in this case might be a good solution

Comment: A database is definitely the way to go about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No,It is not possible.That is what `database` for.Use `database` to store the changes,because that is the easiest and best way to do it.

Or you can store it as a `file` as well.This link might be useful,if you are not familiar with `file handling`.

http://davidwalsh.name/basic-php-file-handling-create-open-read-write-append-close-delete

Yet again,using `database` is better choice.

Answer (score 0):

You have to save it somewhere in permanent storage.  You get to choose - either a database or file.  So if you don't want to store it in a DB, then store it in a file.

However when your data becomes complex and you want to link data to each other, you really need to go to a database.

Comment: This answer is technically correct, but c'mon. Really?

Comment: :) - I didn't say his design is good.  You have concurrency issues - what happens when two people edit the file at the same time?  Security problems to handle when lets say somebody write php code or html code to the file.  It answers his question - he just needs to figure out how to handle it to meet his scope.

Comment: There are ways around all of that, `flock()` etc, I just meant, why bother answering a question like this which is simply someone needing to spend a few mins searching/reading (less time than writing the question..). "I have done some research on this topic but couldn't come up with a solution" - The following took me 3 seconds: https://www.google.co.uk/?gws_rd=ssl#q=php+store+data+without+database

Comment: @James but you couldn't find the solution in 3 min.We all here to learn,not to poke each other

Comment: Read something about Stackoverflow and it says clearly "We are here to learn from our peers".And,if I could find the solution,I was looking for,I won't post the question because it takes time to post a question here(because of formatting).Please be friendly and helpful

Answer (score -1):

Probably not what you're asking, but you can save data until you close the browser using sessions.

Start your script with:

```
<?php
session_start();
```

Then, save data inside `$_SESSION`:

```
$_SESSION['x'] = 'Whatever';
$_SESSION['hi'] = 'Great!';
```

Everything inside $_SESSION will stay even if you reload the page, until you close the browser.

If not, write bunch of JSON files to the filesystem.

Comment: How would other users see it?

Comment: I need other users to see the changes.Like template based site.logged in user change something and other users can see when visit that page

Comment: I don't think you have many choices, it's either a database, or filesystem. If you can't do that, take a look at http://parse.com or similar services, which allow you to save data via an API.